# JQuery, new JS function syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

Can someone explain me the syntax below line 1?
I am OK with js and function references, but this code looks a bit confusing.
E.g. is it function declaration and execution?

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly.
You create an anonymous function which takes one parameter, and immediately invoke it with the parameter `jQuery`.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. For some reason declaration and execution in my mind counln't co-exist.